# POI overriding the old excel sheet with new excel sheet

Tags: java, excel, selenium, webdriver, apache-poi

if i create a first sheet it is working fine. if i call the same method to create new sheet it will over ride the previous sheet.

After couple of method calls, it is showing only one sheet(last sheet).
In my code every time i am creating sheet only, not workbook every time.

could any body please explain.how to code it.

Comment: does the file name change every time? if not change it.. have some random value.. may be a time value

Comment: SO is not for helping you write code.. its for helping you issues with code.

Answer (score 0):

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputString)
```

I am assuming you are using this. When you add the boolean "true" to this syntax like this:

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputString, true);
```

Data will get added to the existing data. You should give it a try.